# Don't include `node_modules` in WebPack sourcemaps

Tags: webpack, source-maps

It seems like the documented way to prevent vendor code from being sourcemapped is to do something like this:

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: '[name].js.map',
  exclude: ['vendor.js']
})
```

**Is there a way to prevent anything in `node_modules` from being added to the sourcemap, without splitting it out into a separate bundle?**